# Tizen support for C++ 11 standard

Tags: c++11, tizen

I am beginning Tizen application developer.

I would like to know what is current support for C++11 features on Tizen?

When will the C++11 standard be fully supported? Maybe some platform developers could shed a light on that topic.

Comment: Tizen does not care about that, it is up to the compiler. And it is most likely supported.

Comment: Check which C++ compilers and STL implementations the Tizen SDK comes with, then look up the C++11 status for those on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tizen 2.3 SDK comes with clang++ version 3.4 and gcc 4.8.

gcc 4.8 is known to not adhere to the C++11 and C++14 standards, clang++ 3.4 is really close to complete for C++11.

However, there's more to C++11 compliance than just the compiler. You also need to have enough support in the C++ library. GCC and Clang have different C++ library projects.
As far as I can quickly tell, Tizen 2.3 ships version 2.13 - which is from 2011.

So don't get your hopes up: things like move semantics, std::mutex, std::async will work, but smaller details like thread local storage will not.