# C++ version for Tizen 2.4

Tags: tizen

From the documentation of Tizen 2.4 it's not clear what major C++ version it supports. So what version of C++ does Tizen 2.4 support and how to set it up in the IDE?

Answer (score 6):

By default Tizen SDK uses GCC 4.9. If your sdk by default use previous version of GCC 4.9, then you can change it to GCC 4.9

When i used C++ in tizen, it showed error in C++ library(string, STL library etc) specific code but it works fine in OOP feature . I used following OOP feature in Tizen app without facing any problem

1. Class
2. Inheritance
3. overloading and overridding

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you're asking about toolchain version of Tizen SDK using.

You can check that from IDE's project preference page. The preference page can be open as belows.

1. Right Click on your project folder on the Project Explorer.(Let me call 'projectA')
2. Click 'Properties' on the context menu

[image]

3. On the 'Properties' page , select C/C++ Build > Tizen Settings
4. You can check the c++ compiler version and change Toolchain informations (LLVM GCC-4.9 / GCC-4.9) like this.
   [image]

I hope this would help you~.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this post.

[Tizen support for C++ 11 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527576/tizen-support-for-c-11-standard)

c++11 is almost supported after Tizen SDK 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Tizen (even 3.0) support gcc4.9 so You can use all the Language features up to C++1y.
If you're really into c++ in Tizen you should definitely check out http://Tizen.jdm.host You can find there articles with nice and clean examples of C++ dev for Tizen as well as some helper functions, classes.

Answer (score -1):

If you plan to use Intel compiler, then it is related to the specific icpc version. There is an [example and a tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-c-compiler-for-tizen) from January 2014.